# Customizing the source and target locations in a makefile

Tags: c, makefile, toolkit

I am a newbie to Creo toolkit. For trial purpose, I need to edit the location of the source and target folders in the default make-file available. A part of the make-file is given below for reference.

```
# File Name
MAKEFILENAME = make_install

# Machine Type
PRO_MACHINE_TYPE = x86e_win64

# Executable names
EXE = pt_inst_test.exe
EXE_DLL = pt_inst_test.dll

# Pro/Toolkit Source & Machine Loadpoint  (EXTERNAL USE - DEFAULT)
PROTOOL_SRC = $(PROE_INSTALL_PATH)\protoolkit
PROTOOL_SYS = $(PROTOOL_SRC)/$(PRO_MACHINE_TYPE)

# Pro/Toolkit Source & Machine Loadpoint  (PTC INTERNAL USE)
#PROTOOL_SRC = $(PTCSRC)/protoolkit
#PROTOOL_SYS = $(PTCSYS)

# Include File Paths
INCS = -I. -I$(PROTOOL_SRC)/protk_appls/includes -I$(PROTOOL_SRC)/includes
```

In the above given code, I need to replace the source (PROE_INSTALL _PATH) with the required folder location (For ex: C:\Users\sagarp\Desktop\trial) without editing the environment variable. Is it possible? If so, please help me with the basics of creating a make-file on my own.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your problem is unclear. A makefile cannot be written in C. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If we don't see the Makefile we can't help you, except if the problem is clearly exposed which is not the case here.

Comment: You don't even need to edit it. Fust run `make PROE_INSTALL_PATH="value"`

Comment: Even if i run the makefile in visual studio command prompt, I get a fatal error as U1073: dont know to make.

Comment: Hello Nelson. Just to clarify, PROE_INSTALL_PATH shall be the location of your complete creo install. As you will see further in the makefile, this variable is used to build the standard header files that are given to the compiler's -I option. In other words, this is not the path to your source code

Answer (score -1):

I just started using Creo toolkit and saw this question.

It's an old question but I'd still post the answer.

You can update the

```
PROTOOL_SRC = $(PROE_INSTALL_PATH)\protoolkit
```

by giving relative path.

It could be current dir or whatever you prefer.

Example for current dir :

```
PROTOOL_SRC = .

PROTOOL_SYS = $(PROTOOL_SRC)/$(PRO_MACHINE_TYPE)
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: oh.. It's a batch file and I think for this much of code it is formatted :)